# ZeroMQ in Eclipse CDT

Tags: c++, ipc, eclipse-cdt, zeromq

I am trying to install ZeroMQ for Windows 10 64bit, and to use it with Eclipse CDT to connect python and C++. 
I read the [documentation](http://zeromq.org/intro:get-the-software), and it says that it needs to be compiled with CMake for the Visual Studio libraries. I cannot find any information about Eclipse for C++. How can I use it in Eclipse CDT?

Comment: Eclipse is irrelevant, you need binaries that are compatible with your C++ compiler.